# SF Workbench - API Version - v55 Not Appearing

Tags: api, deployment, workbench, deployment-api

I require to use Workbench with SF API v55 (Summer '22) so that I may deploy Service Cloud Voice (SCV) Contact Center with features that are in v55

My SF Org is running Summer '22 (v55)

Currently when I select the dropdown for APIs I only see v54, a week or so ago there was v55

Where did it go?

Thanks

[image: SF Workbench - Where Is API v55? Only seeing v54!]

Comment: It's pending: https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/pull/850 . If you're in a hurry you can have your own, private instance of Workbench on Heroku, nearly a one-click experience via https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

- There is currently a **pending** **Pull Request** for **forceworkbench**

  - Which will make the changes to use API **v55** from **v54**.
- https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/pull/850

Thank you [@identigral](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4142/identigral) for your help

Comment: The following Pull Request has been Merged in for the SF - Force Workbench master branch which allows the v55 of the API to be used. 

Comment: Currently this is also the same v60